For Lightning, can I have a field Lookup Filter that allows a blank lookup value when the path update button is clicked?
This lookup field filter on a field labelled "Fund Bank Account" on an object labelled "Distribution":

works well when a user is editing the lookup field. It only offers Fund Bank Account records to complete the lookup that are tied to the same Fund ID that the record being edited (the Distribution) is tied to.
In normal editing the record can be saved when the "Fund Bank Account" lookup field is left empty - that field is not marked as required at the field level or in the page.
But with the "Fund Bank Account" lookup field empty, when the path component's path update button is used to change the stage (problem does not happen when the stage is manually edited - bizarre) this error toast is output and the edit fails:
[
For searchability the text is:
You encountered some errors when trying to save this record
These required fields must be completed: Fund Bank Account

This appears to be independently enforced: no lookup filter "Filter Criteria" that I tried appeared to make any difference, and the lookup filter "Error Message" never appeared, just this error toast.
This is an area that has some changes  from Classic:

In Salesforce Classic, administrators can make lookup filters required or optional. In Lightning Experience, all lookup filters are required, even if admins specify them as optional in Setup.

Can I have a field Lookup Filter that allows a blank lookup value when a path "Mark as Current Progress" is clicked?

You can literally have: "Fund Bank Account: Fund ID Equals Distribution: Fund ID OR Fund Bank Account: Fund ID Equals" with the second term stating Value comparison and no value.

Thanks @PhilW, I did try that but will try it again to be sure. Note that the message displayed is "These required fields..." not "Value does not exist..." defied i the lookup filter.

Found my problem.
The "Fund Bank Account" was marked as required in the page layout and changing that fixed the problem. So looks like the path update button interacts with the Classic page layout but a normal save does not.
